# Find Facebook post by photo object_id using fql or graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have photo lists that uploaded by me.

But, can't find a post(and comments, likes of a post) that include multiple photos in an one post using photo object_id.

It is easy to find comments, likes of a post includes single photo using photo object_id.
On the other hand, it's hard to find comments, likes of a post includes multiple photos using specific photo object_id.

Comment: Pretty sure that a post will only have one photo associated with it. When you see posts with multiple photos this is actually where an album has been posted. Look for the comments and likes in the albums - e.g. via https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums

Comment: Maybe use the pid (Photo Id). Is there no way to use that field to achieve your expected result ?